# twisted python ISFTPServer openDirectory

Tags: python, twisted

I've been working through twisted to make an sftp server and am having trouble returning any information from my ISFTPServer.openDirectory function.

EX

```
class MySFTPAdapter:
    implements(filetransfer.ISFTPServer)
    def openDirectory(self, path):
        return ('test', 'drwxrwxrwx    1 ab       cd              0 Apr 23 15:41 test', {'size': 0, 'uid': 1000, 'gid': 1000, 'mtime': 1366746069L, 'atime': 1366746069L, 'permissions': 511})
```

Fails with

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "sftpserver.py", line 435, in dataReceived
    f(data)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/twisted/conch/ssh/filetransfer.py", line 265, in packet_OPENDIR
    d.addCallback(self._cbOpenDirectory, requestId)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/twisted/internet/defer.py", line 260, in addCallback
    callbackKeywords=kw)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/twisted/internet/defer.py", line 249, in addCallbacks
    self._runCallbacks()
--- <exception caught here> ---
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/twisted/internet/defer.py", line 441, in _runCallbacks
    self.result = callback(self.result, *args, **kw)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/twisted/conch/ssh/filetransfer.py", line 269, in _cbOpenDirectory
    handle = str(hash(dirObj))
exceptions.TypeError: unhashable type: 'dict'
```

The exception frame locals are;

```
{'val': ('test', 'drwxrwxrwx    1 ab       cd              0 Apr 23 15:41 test', {'size': 0, 'uid': 1000, 'gid': 1000, 'mtime': 1366746069L, 'atime': 1366746069L, 'permissions': 511})}
```

Anyone have an idea what's up or what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your implementation of `openDirectory`:

```
def openDirectory(self, path):
    return ('test',
            'drwxrwxrwx    1 ab       cd              0 Apr 23 15:41 test',
            {'size': 0, 'uid': 1000, 'gid': 1000, 'mtime': 1366746069L,
             'atime': 1366746069L, 'permissions': 511})
```

returns a tuple of three elements.  From the interface documentation:

```
    This method returns an iterable object that has a close() method,                                                                      
    or a Deferred that is called back with same.                                                                                           

    The close() method is called when the client is finished reading                                                                       
    from the directory.  At this point, the iterable will no longer                                                                        
    be used.                                                                                                                               

    The iterable should return triples of the form (filename,                                                                              
    longname, attrs) or Deferreds that return the same.  The                                                                               
    sequence must support __getitem__, but otherwise may be any                                                                            
    'sequence-like' object.
```

The tuple you returned sounds like an *element* of the iterator being discussed here, rather than the whole return value.

Try something like:

```
def openDirectory(self, path):
    yield ('test',
           'drwxrwxrwx    1 ab       cd              0 Apr 23 15:41 test',
           {'size': 0, 'uid': 1000, 'gid': 1000, 'mtime': 1366746069L,
            'atime': 1366746069L, 'permissions': 511})
```

Now you have a generator - which is an iterator with a close method - the elements of which are three-tuples as described in the documentation.

Comment: *edit ok that did work.
Do you know of how I can do this with a decorator of @defer.inlineCallbacks / is that possible?
Also, sorry I can't upvote you as I don't have enough reputation

Comment: I suspect that what you want to do with `inlineCallbacks` is not easy.  When you decorate a function with `inlineCallbacks`, it becomes a function that returns a `Deferred` that fires with one value supplied at the end of the generator.  However, if you just yield Deferreds *without* using `inlineCallbacks`, you might get close to the behavior you want.  Read the interface documentation carefully, and pay special attention to where it says you are allowed to give out a Deferred.  The support for Deferreds built in to the interface may be enough to make your job easy.